# Network unaccessible in Dockerfile when run with Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apt-get

In my project, apt-get fails to work from Dockerfile when I launch it with `docker-compose`. But when I call docker directly with `--network` option, it does work.

Here are configs:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  main:
    build: main
    network_mode: host
```

`main/Dockefile`:

```
FROM osrm/osrm-backend:v5.22.0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget nodejs npm osmium-tool
```

This fails (apt-get can't lookup a domain):

```
sudo docker-compose build main
```

This does work:

```
sudo docker build main --network=host
```

What's the reason, how to fix it?

Host system is Ubuntu 20.04.

**EDIT:** Got fixed itself. Well, not itself, but I can't point at what I did exactly to fix it. I was changing `/etc/docker/daemon.conf` back and forth and rebooted.

Docker compose reads:

```
version: '3'

services:
  main: 
    build: main
```

That's it. `main/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM osrm/osrm-backend:v5.22.0
RUN echo 123321 && cat /etc/resolv.conf  # echo $number to prevent caching
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install osmium-tool
```

`/etc/docker/daemon.conf`:

```
{}
```

`/etc/default/docker`:

```
...
DOCKER_OPTS=" --dns 127.0.0.53"
...
```

127.0.0.53 is Ubuntu own DNS forwarding daemon, if I understood the docs correctly.

Running `$ docker-compose build main` prints me:

```
Building main
Step 1/5 : FROM osrm/osrm-backend:v5.22.0
 ---> daceec677b86
Step 2/5 : RUN echo 32231 && cat /etc/resolv.conf
 ---> Running in d8c54a39faee
32231
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
...
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver <provider dns ip>
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.0.1
search <my wifi router>
Removing intermediate container d8c54a39faee
 ---> 4b07a0fcc889
Step 3/5 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install osmium-tool
 ---> Running in 71a7c887af04
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [53.0 kB]
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
```

Everything works.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I suspect it has something to do with the network DNS for the container built by a Dockerfile but I haven't figured out how to get around it yet.

I saw there is an open issue on Github for the particular error message(s) that I'm getting. What are your error messages?

Comment: My errors:
`fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main: temporary error (try again later)
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.2c4ac24e.tar.gz: No such file or directory
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz`

Comment: `ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/community: temporary error (try again later)
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.40a3604f.tar.gz: No such file or directory
2 errors; 14 distinct packages available
ERROR: Service 'apache_php-fpm_backend' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk update &&     apk add --update git &&     apk add --update openssh' returned a non-zero code: 2`

Comment: @kanidrive I see it has the same resolv.conf as it should be (defined by some docker configs) but nothing happens, DNS fails on `apt update`.

Comment: I added + updated an answer for this question. If the `firewall-cmd` rule tweak(s) doesn't give you the fix you need, try setting the FirewallBackend value to = iptables and reload/restart firewall and restart docker service and try again. I had to fuss around A LOT with this but I do seem to have it working consistently on CentOS8 now (I don't seem to have this issue with building Dockerfile-based containers via docker-composer.yml on Debian-based Linux flavors.)

Answer (score 3):

UPDATED ANSWER:

`sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade --permanent;`

`sudo firewall-cmd --reload`

`sudo systemctl restart docker`

[You can even get more granular with firewall-cmd rules using the answers found here.](https://serverfault.com/questions/987686/no-network-connectivity-to-from-docker-ce-container-on-centos-8/994704)

This seemed to fix this issue for me from a "fresh install" of CentOS8. This IP Tables rule has a lot of nuances to it, but [this thread seems to really have all the details](https://serverfault.com/questions/987686/no-network-connectivity-to-from-docker-ce-container-on-centos-8/994704#994704) you could need, should you have a need for highly sensitive security concerns & settings.

Original Answer: I found a workaround for this issue on a CentOS host:

https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/386#issuecomment-665123736

Modify the following section in `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf`:

```
...
# FirewallBackend
# Selects the firewall backend implementation.
# Choices are:
#       - nftables (default)
#       - iptables (iptables, ip6tables, ebtables and ipset)
##FirewallBackend=nftables
FirewallBackend=iptables
...
```

Then:
`service firewalld restart`

After that when I ran `docker-compose up ...` on my docker-compose.yml all was right in the world again.

Comment: hmm, in my case the host os is Ubuntu, and there's no such service as firewalld. I couldn't find any advices on ubuntu firewall, if it might have been the reason.

Comment: Ah, what errors are you seeing when the `docker build ...` command fails? Can you share with us the output?

Comment: surprisingly, when I tried to produce an error output for you it worked. Seems that tinkering with docker config and a reboot made it work.

`/etc/docker/daemon.json` is just empty object `{}`, and `/etc/resolv.conf` inside the container reads `nameserver <provider dns><br>nameserver 8.8.8.8<br>nameserver 192.168.0.1<br>search <router_name>`.

Comment: I think another edit that could have fixed this was `/etc/default/docker`: `DOCKER_OPTS=" --dns 127.0.0.53" # --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 --dns 192.168.0.1"`
 (I remember these settings didn't change anything that day, but after a reboot today it started working.)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on an oracle VM. The same docker build that worked on my local machine did not work there. All I needed to do to fix that was

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```